# How to change textwidth for all file types in Vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, how do I change the textwidth (the amount of characters that can be displayed across the screen) so that it impacts all file types.

I currently have this line in my .vimrc file

```
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=100
```

How can I change this so it applies to all file types, not just text files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By removing the "filetype" parts:

```
set textwidth=100
```